# TS property detail.registerProperties of extension news does not work for datetime

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

The [news docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#detail-registerproperties) say I should set up the following code in plugin settings to get access to the corresponding register value per ts.

```
plugin.tx_news {
  settings {
      detail {
          registerProperties = keywords,title,datetime
      }
  }
}
```

This works for the title property:

```
20 = TEXT
20 {
    data = register:newsTitle
}
```

But not for datetime:

```
20 = TEXT
20 {
    data = register:newsDatetime
}
```

I also tested crdate, tstamp and the notation newsDateTime but nothing works.

How I get access to datetime of a news item in detail view with typoscript?
Thanks in advance

Update:
If I output all registers with

```
data = debug:register
```

I get

[image: screenshot]

But I didn´t know how I can access these newsDatetime => DateTime object within TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in the extension itself. I created an issue at https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/613 for it.

what you could do to fix this is to extend the extension described in the manual at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/github/georgringer/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ProxyClassGenerator/Index.html and use a custom getter which returns the timestamp of the field.

This has been now fixed with https://github.com/georgringer/news/commit/964e92d5043ee596d7e97a1b40986756a89a93a5 and will be part of version 7.0.0

Comment: Thanks for explanation the bug. Hopefully It get fixed quick :-)

Comment: Totally forgot to thanks for open an issue on github :-)